# Paginate must return 206 and not 200

Tags: laravel, pagination

I understood that one best practice when using paginate with an api, is to return a response code 206 "partial content". But when I am doing :

```
$users = DB::table('users')->paginate(15);
```

and then

```
return response()->json($users)
```

it returns a response 200.

So, how to return a 206 and not a 200 when using Laravel with api and paginate function ? Does it exist something ? or is it my responsibility to manage this response ?

### Edit

Of course I can pass 2O6 in the second parameter. But I expect something more intelligent, something which will return automatically 206 or 200 depending the paginate result.

Comment: Hi @Dom, if you want to automatically returning `206`, you can make a helper to override `response()->json($users, 'code')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use second parameter :

```
return response()->json($users, 206)
```

---

#### Update

If you want to automatically returning `206`, you can make a helper to override `response()->json($users, 'code')`.

I have a [helper package](https://github.com/Kristories/laravel-helpers) that can help you.

```
composer require kristories/laravel-helpers
```

Then create a new helper :

```
php artisan make:helper JsonResponseHelper
```

Edit `app/Helpers/JsonResponseHelper.php` :

```php
function paginateResponse($data = []){
    return response()->json($data, 206);
}
```

**Usage**

Now, you can use `paginateResponse()` :

```php
return paginateResponse($users);
```

Comment: Hi Wahyu Kristianto, thanks for your answer. I edited my initial post.

Comment: Hi Wahyu, good idea to override the default response. I will be inspired by your suggestion. Even I can count the $data to decide if it must return 200 or 206. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

you can pass it on second parameter;

```
return response()->json($users, 206);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it